# How can I get the login status of user using JWT in angular-4 using golang as API server

Tags: angular, session, go, authentication, token

I am new to go language or golang and I am creating an application using  Angular-4 as front-end and go as API server. The database I that am using is mongodb.

So, I have created an endpoint APIs using `gin` in go.

The APIs are working good and I have created a login API which gets the email and password and if email and password is correct, it creates a JWT token and returns the JWT token in response.

The JWT token consists of following things :

- userId.
- User Role.
- Current server time.

If the user's email and password is correct the server create a JWT token and saved it in the user's collection and return it to the client side and saved it to the local storage.

I want to save the token to the server like in PHP or Java applications.
Someone advised me to store the JWT token in server local storage or memory instead of saving it to the user's cookie.

I am using `gin` package not `http` package. So please help me with the reference of **`gin`** package.

I have searched too much for the session but I found the way related to `http` and I have also read about `gorilla`'s session but what I get is it is for `client` side and I want to save the token on **server** side.

Comment: Is there any problem in this question? Please kindly read the whole question first and than vote it down. 
There question is different.

Comment: why do you need both JWT and session? i've created a single page app using vue.js using go as API server, IMHO, you don't need both, you either use JWT or session. i'm saving the JWT token on cookie.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have save JWT in local storage. But how can I detect a user is login or not? So thats why I have to use session or something which can be used to store token at server so I can check the user status.

Comment: maybe that's a nice thing that I also want in my app. i'm not sure about this, but what about some kind of refresh function in javascript that runs let's say every 10-20 minutes? but i think it can be really heavy for your server. you'll still use your JWT token for that.

Comment: I have saved a JWT token in local storage. So yes server would be heavy that it will check the token validation time and when a user do any request on server it will also check the token but it would be the secure way to do it. What do you think @srxf ?

Comment: to be honest, i'm not really sure about it, as far as i know, JWTs are meant to be stateless, so i would say just try implementing what you think would work in your case. anyway, try reading [this](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/), it might help you decide what you really want for your app. cheers man!

Answer (score 0):

There is no local storage for server like for the webs... There are databases for these purposes. Use Mongodb instead if you're using it as a database...
Or use global variables on server side.
But I would suggest db.

Comment: You are absolutely right @Muhammad Kashif Sulaiman. But I have already save token in DB and if I find and check user from db by token, it be a long process. Can you tell me a short/easy way to do it?

Comment: if you don't wanna use db, then use global variables.
For e.g.
tokensList = [{ <uid>: <token> }, { <uid> : <token> }]